# How to embed cell text into part of a formula in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

This seems like it should be simple, but I can't wrap my brain around it...

I have an Excel Formula that pulls a specific cell from a pivot table.

exact formula:

```
=IFERROR(GETPIVOTDATA("[Measures].[MyMeasure]",'Average HC pivot'!$B$4,"[HC_Data].[trade]","[HC_Data].[trade].&[Accounting / Finance]"),0)
```

now what I need it to be able to replace **Accounting / Finance** to other trades that are listed in a reference column while keeping the formula working.

for context, `Accounting / Finance` is in cell `A15`

`HR` is in cell `A16` and so on...

my thought was to simply write the formula as:

```
=IFERROR(GETPIVOTDATA("[Measures].[MyMeasure]",'Average HC pivot'!$B$4,"[HC_Data].[trade]","[HC_Data].[trade].&[A15]"),0)
```

but this doesn't work since the formula pulls from a pivot table?

my current workaround is a **concatenate** formula that pulls 3 portions of the formula together:

```
=IFERROR(GETPIVOTDATA("[Measures].[MyMeasure]",'Average HC pivot'!$B$4,"[HC_Data].[trade]","[HC_Data].[trade].&[<Trade in column A>]"),0)
```

however, this is tedious as the Trades in column `A` change as the data is updated and the Concatenated "formula" would need to be repasted every time the data is changed

this workaround "could" work with less hassle, but since the formula I'm after is imbedded in the concatenate function, I need to paste the formula as "values" (text), the pasted formula doesn't automatically return the data since it is pasted as text. would there be a quick way to return the text into a formula aside from double clicking into the cell and pressing enter?

any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

```
=IFERROR(GETPIVOTDATA("[Measures].[MyMeasure]",'Average HC pivot'!$B$4,
"[HC_Data].[trade]","[HC_Data].[trade].&[Accounting / Finance]"),0)
```

I don't use GETPIVOTDATA() much but I feel "uneasy" about the `&` being inside the double quotes, and maybe should be:

```
=IFERROR(GETPIVOTDATA("[Measures].[MyMeasure]",'Average HC pivot'!$B$4,
"[HC_Data].[trade]","[HC_Data].[trade].[Accounting / Finance]"),0)
```

And thus the "variablized" version shouldn't be:

```
=IFERROR(GETPIVOTDATA("[Measures].[MyMeasure]",'Average HC pivot'!$B$4,
"[HC_Data].[trade]","[HC_Data].[trade].&[A15]"),0)
```

But rather, should be:

```
=IFERROR(GETPIVOTDATA("[Measures].[MyMeasure]",'Average HC pivot'!$B$4," 
[HC_Data].[trade]","""[HC_Data].[trade].[" & A15 & "]"""),0)
```

In my mind, your `A15` will never be interpreted because it is inside an explicit quotation.  We need to get A15 outside of the quotes to get Excel to interpret it as a cell location, get the contents of A15, and place it in the concatenation.  The result still needs to be inside double quotes for GETPIVOTDATA(), so I used the triple `"""` at the beginning and the end to make that result of all the concatenation to end up returned to the formula in a set of double quotes.

If this is incorrect, I'll delete this answer.

Comment: unfortunately, it does not work.

the & sign is automatically generated in the GETPIVOTDATA and if it is deleted, it returns 0.

i thought i could do a simpl XLOOKUP, but this returns the exact column specified in the formula, and if there are added month columns in the pivot, it breaks as well.

i did add A15 as part of the concatenate, so it reduced the total columns needed for this project, but the issue remains that the cells paste the formula as text.

is there not an easy way to convert the text to a formula similar to how numbers stored as text can be "reformatted" as numbers?